# c#....my while loop keep repeating

Tags: c#

i am trying to get my while loop to ONLY keep repeating till all subjects have been answered, then it should stop and display the bonus and final score. but don't know why its not doing that? help please.

```
namespace Assignment
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static int attempt, sum, AptScore, GenScore, MathScore, EngScore, bonus, TotalScore, FinalScore, choice = 0;
        public static string ans;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool stop = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to this Salisbury University IQ Test game");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("How many times have you attempted this test?");
            attempt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (true)
                if (attempt > 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You cannot take this test");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" \n1. Aptitude \n2. English. \n3. Math \n4. Gk \n5. Exit");
                    choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    switch (choice)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine(" What was the name of the lebanon tyrant who ruled for years unending before he was toppled due to civil war? \nA. Osama Bin laden \nB. Gaddafi \nC. Jonathan ");
                            ans = Console.ReadLine();
                            if (ans == "B" || ans == "b")
                            {
                                AptScore += 10;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.WriteLine(" What is the antonym of Pleasure? \nA. Pain \nB. Ecstacy \nC. Wonder");
                            ans = Console.ReadLine();
                            if (ans == "A" || ans == "a")
                            {
                                EngScore += 10;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.WriteLine(" What is the sum of 435 and 345? \nA. 799 \nB. 780 \nC. 600 ");
                            ans = Console.ReadLine();
                            if (ans == "B" || ans == "b")
                            {
                                MathScore += 10;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Console.WriteLine(" What year did Nigeria become a republic? \nA. 1960 \nB. 1963 \nC. 1990 ");
                            ans = Console.ReadLine();
                            if (ans == "B" || ans == "b")
                            {
                                GenScore += 10;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                            break;
                    }
                    if (stop)
                        break;
                    TotalScore = MathScore + GenScore + EngScore + AptScore;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your total score is : " + TotalScore);
                    if (TotalScore == 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" You have no Bonus point ");
                    }
                    else if (TotalScore == 20)
                    {
                        bonus += 2;
                        Console.WriteLine("Your Bonus is {0}", bonus);
                    }
                    else if (TotalScore == 30)
                    {
                        bonus += 5;
                        Console.WriteLine("Your Bonus is {0}", bonus);
                    }
                    else if (TotalScore == 40)
                    {
                        bonus += 10;
                        Console.WriteLine("Your Bonus is {0}", bonus);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FinalScore = TotalScore + bonus;
                        Console.WriteLine("Your finalscore is : " + FinalScore);
                    }
                    switch (FinalScore)
                    {
                        case 10:
                            if (FinalScore >= 10)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Your IQ level is below average");
                            }
                            break;
                        case 22:
                            if (FinalScore >= 22)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Your IQ level is average");
                            }
                            break;
                        case 35:
                            if (FinalScore >= 35)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("You are intelligent");
                            }
                            break;
                        case 40:
                            if (FinalScore == 40)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("You are a genius");
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you break out of your infinite loop (`while (true)`)? I don't see it.

Comment: @Oded Very true. There is no break out of the while loop.

Comment: @JayPatel @Oded:  There is a `if (stop) break;` statement.  Unfortunately, `stop` is never set to `true`.

Comment: @abelenky Thanks. I did not notice that.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (stop)
    break;
```

This never happens.

Answer (score 1):

I see:

```
bool stop = false;
```

and also:

```
if (stop)
    break;
```

But I never see a `stop = true;`

Where do you intend to set stop to true?